# IndexError: list index out of range when using np.argmax function

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am working on an action recognition problem with CNN-LSTM and converted all the frames to CSV files. I trained my model and saved the model in h5 form. After training, when I am testing on a video file using open cv it is throwing an error. Below is my code:-

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model



model = load_model("C:/Users/Sonu/Desktop/important/model.h5")

model.summary()
classes = ['goal', 'free', 'credit']
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("C:/Users/Sonu/Desktop/important/out1.mp4")

while cap.isOpened():
    _, frame = cap.read()

    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    resized = cv2.resize(frame, (51250, 50), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    frame = resized.reshape(1, 1025, 50, 50, 3)

    pred_array = model.predict(frame)
    print(pred_array)

    result = classes[np.argmax(pred_array)]
    #result = classes[pred_array][0]

    score = float("%0.2f" % (max(pred_array[0]) * 100))
    #score = float("{.2f}".format((classes) * 100))
    print(f'Result: {result}, Score: {score}')

    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)


    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

The error log is as follows:-

```
File "C:/Users/Sonu/Desktop/important/detecting_video_lrcnn.py", line 32, in <module>
    result = classes[np.argmax(pred_array)]


IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anyone guide me where I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance folks.

Answer (score 0):

Without running the code, I believe your problem is with the `pred_array = model.predict(frame)` line. It is only fair to assume that `pred_array` is of length greater than 3, i.e. the length of your `class` array. So if `pred_array` is any bigger than length 3 and the largest element is at a position greater than that, `result = classes[np.argmax(pred_array)]` will be causing the IndexError error message that you are receiving.

Hope this helps clarify where your problem might be!